# Jenkins - Level of console output

Tags: maven, logging, jenkins

I have a Jenkins install on Debian.
All jobs run but the console output of all Maven build have an INFO level. I need to have ALL level on these console output.

I confess to have problems to understand the log configuration of Jenkins.

I seen : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging
but I don't understand what I need to fill in "Logger" to point to all jobs registered in Jenkins.
I tried to have a general Log with an empty "Logger name" in target scope, it seems that works on "Jenkins log" but not on "Jobs console output".

Thanks you for you help,

Elodie

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in current version of jenkins:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19352

At 2013-10-05 a commit was made to address it, but as of today (2013-10-08) there is no release including this fix.